# LaraveL : How to get data from many to many relationship

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have 3 tables which are `user`->id, name,password, `roles`->id,role, `role_user`->role_id, user_id

Now if I want to show the associated data in view page means role related to user ..How i do it in view?
means I want to show if the user has role it will be checked otherwise it will be unchecked

Here is my controller :

```
$users = User::all();
$roles = Role::all();
return view("Permission::assign_role",compact('users','roles'));
```

View page

```
<table class="table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>SL No</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Role</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($users->roles() as $row)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$i}}</td>
        <td>{{$row->name}}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" name="role_id" checked> $role->role</td>
    </tr>

    <?php $i++; ?>

    @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

[Eager load](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) the data:

```
$users = User::with('roles')->get();
return view("Permission::assign_role", compact('users'));
```

And in the view, you can do something like this if you want to check if user has specific role:

```
@if ($user->roles->contains($roleId))
```

If you want to just iterate over user's roles:

```
@foreach($users->roles as $role)
    {{ $role->name }}
```

Comment: when I tried to get the property of `{{$role->role}}` as role is the property name , i see the following Error `Property [roles] does not exist on this collection instance.`

Comment: @User57 use `dd()` to see what data it has. Like this `{{ dd($role) }}`

Comment: when i `dd($users)`,in  "roles" => Collection I got the following output `#attributes: array:5 [▼
                "id" => 1
                "role" => "admin"
                "label" => "Admin"
                "created_at" => "2017-03-11 06:02:12"
                "updated_at" => "2017-03-11 06:02:12"`

Comment: @User57 then you do it right and getting an error in another part of the view. The error says you're using `roles` instead of `role` somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

This how I am using for my applications :

User Model :

```
public function roles() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Role::class);
    }
```

Role Model :

```
public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }
```

In My Controller :

```
$users = User::all();
```

In My View

```
@foreach($users as $user)
   @foreach($user->roles() as $role)
     {{$role->name}}
   @endforeach
 @endforeach
```

Comment: Nothing came out form database..I see blank page from your solution